# how to access the Php return json encoded array elements in the ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a vote system that is similar tho youtube vote system.once I sent the relevant data to the php function i want to get back the query results back to the ajax function.I have array of likes and dislikes .when I encoded the array ajax success function returns as follows.
{"likes":2,"unlikes":0}
I want to get likes and unlike values(2 and 1) to display in the html page.
how can I get them.

user-likes.js

```
        function liked(answerId) {

            var anID = answerId;
            var clickedIcon = $('#Like');
            //var nextIcon=$('#like')

            $.ajax({
                dataType:'json',
                url: 'vote.php' ,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'liked': 1,
                    'postid': anID

                },
                success: function (results) {


                    alert(results);

                    clickedIcon.removeClass();
                    clickedIcon.addClass('mdi-action-thumb-up teal-text');
                    //.text(res[0].likes);


                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
        }
```

vote.php

```
    <? php include '../../backend/connection.php';
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];


    if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
        $answerId = $_POST['postid'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM answervote WHERE aID='" . $answerId . "'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $nUp =(int)($row['voteUpCount'])+1 ;

        $nDown=(int)$row['voteDownCount'];
        $law_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT aUser FROM answer WHERE aID='" . $answerId . "'");
        $law = mysqli_fetch_array($law_query);
        $lawyer_name=$law['aUser'];

        $point_query=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT points FROM lawyer  WHERE username='".$lawyer_name."'");
        $point_result=mysqli_fetch_array($point_query);

        $points=$point_result['points']+1;



        try{

            mysqli_autocommit($connection, FALSE);
            mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE lawyer SET points='$points' WHERE username='".$lawyer_name."'");
            mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO likes(username,aID) VALUES ('$username','$answerId')");
            mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE answervote SET voteUpCount='$nUp' WHERE aID ='" . $answerId . "'");
            mysqli_commit($connection);
        }catch(Exception $e ){
            $connection->rollback();

        }
        $ratings=[
            "likes" => $nUp,
            "unlikes"=> $nDown

        ];
        echo json_encode($ratings);


    }
```

returned result from success function:{"likes":2,"unlikes":0}

Comment: have you tried `results.likes`/`results.unlikes`?

Comment: Update the table first and get the result after, or it won't contain the current vote.

Comment: is the output i am getting is correct.I think that the encoded data result should be like this.'[{"likes":2,"unlikes":0}]'

Comment: @Sean it worked.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your success funtion and you will get data

result = $.parseJSON(result);

now console.log(result)  or alert(result)

Comment: is `$.parseJSON` really needed when they have `dataType:'json',`

Comment: @Sean - Nope, it isn't. jQuery will do that for you before returning the result.

Comment: results.likes/results.unlikes and access result like this

Comment: Don't tell _us_. Update your answer instead :-)

Comment: @GirishNinama .I tried  **alert(results.likes)**.only the backend database is updating.

Comment: @oshadhi in alert(results.likes) have u got your desired result  ?

Comment: with $.parseJSON it didnt work.but alert(results.likes) worked.thank you for the help